# Making a semitransparent Theme.Wallpaper

Tags: android

I am trying to set up a child them of `Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar`, but I want it to only be semitransparent. My current style is written as such:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomClear" parent="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:color">#F0000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The ultimate goal is to still be able to see the wallpaper in the background, but darken it so that text is more easily readable. Am I at least on the right track here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. This can be achieved by editing the background property rather than the color property.

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomClear" parent="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:background">#4000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```